# How to use showModalBottomSheet in StatelessWidget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I try to code like this

```
showModalBottomSheet(
   context: context, // I got error here (Undefined name 'context'.dart(undefined_identifier))
   builder: (context){

   return Container(

   );
);
```

I got error on `context: context`, error message is

> Undefined name 'context'.dart(undefined_identifier)

Comment: Are you using it inside `build` method. If possible post full widget class code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you call the `showModalBottomSheet` in a `StatelessWidget`

```
class TestStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Press me'),
      onPressed: ()=>showPress(context),
    );
  }

  void showPress(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(context:context, builder: (context){
      return Text('hello');
    });
  }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you don't have access to `context` everywhere in a `StatelessWidget` class. All you need to do is pass `context` from `build()` if you are using this outside `build()` method else use it within `build()` method.

---

Solution 1. (Using inside `build()`)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Show sheet"),
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => YourWidget());
    },
  );
}
```

Solution 2. (Using outside `build()`)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Show sheet"),
    onPressed: () => _showSheet(context),
  );
}

void _showSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => YourWidget());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your `showModalBottomSheet`'s `builder` correctly.
There is a `}` missing.

This would be the correct usage:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (builder){
      return Container();
    }
);
```